# Rails Font Awesome Icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, icons, font-awesome

I've read a few of the pages on using font awesome with rails and that the Gemfile should include
    `gem 'font-awesome-rails'`
then run bundle install
and the application.css should include
    `*= require font-awesome`
however, when I try to use the icons such as 
    `<i class="icon_home"></i>`
to get the home icon, it shows up as blank, the grey icon should be the home icon
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMCQ2.png)

I have also tried to edit the font-awesome.css file and change the @font face and edit the applications.rb to include the fonts folder as recommended in other pages but I get the same issue

Comment: have you tried with restarting your server?

Comment: +1 to restarting the server. Alternatively, I just ended up including the font-awesome CDN into most of my applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this.

```
<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

If you ever want any icon just go [Here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/home/) and click on icon you want and it will give your HTML for that icon.

Comment: You can also use the provided helpers to generate the icons even more succinctly "here are also some helpers (fa_icon and fa_stacked_icon) that make your views icontastic!" https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/blob/master/README.md#helpers